# keycloak returning error after login No active keys found,

Tags: jhipster, keycloak

I have my app made generated with jhipster. Everything works perfect locally but when I deployed to cloud, I am getting an error with keycloak I can't find the answer to. I have fix the redirect_url issue where you have to add the app url but can't understand this one. help Thanks:)

> [org.keycloak.keys.FailsafeAesKeyProvider] (default task-47) No active
>   keys found, using failsafe provider, please login to admin console to
>   add keys. Clustering is not supported.

Comment: I think this is related to the keys set in the realm settings. So there are some default keys, but you are encouraged to generate new ones regularly according to this https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.1/server_admin/topics/realms/keys.html

Answer (score 1):

This error is occurring because there is no aes generated key present. To solve this, login to the keycloak admin console, go to Realm settings -> Keys -> Providers -> Add keystore -> aes-generated and generate a new key.